# Nuxt how to ignore files for hot-reload

Tags: nuxt.js, capacitor

I use Nuxt.js and Capacitor.js to make an Android application and I have a "android" folder in my Nuxt folder project. How can I ignore this folder for hot-reloading ?
I try to use ignore property in my nuxt.config.js but without success.

```
ignore: [
    'android'
],
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure how capacitor works or what your `android` directory is for, but do you need to have nuxt ignore the directory for everything or just for hot reload ? what about when building the project ?